# US phone area code city/state database?

Tags: data-request, usa

Is there a database that matches each US phone area code to the major city and state that it belongs to?

Comment: Wikipedia has pages like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_code_814 for most (all?) area codes, so you could try scraping that.

Answer (score 2):

The [North American Numbering Plan Administration](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/about_us/index.html) is responsible for the number resources. On their website they have both a [Flash](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/area_code_maps/ac_map_flash.html) and an [HTML](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/area_code_maps/ac_map_static.html) method of looking at the area codes by state. You would need to manually analyze the data, but this is the best source to answer your question.

There are also [excel spreadsheets of the area codes](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/reports/reports_npa.html), but it does not have the city information you are looking for.

Below is the area codes for Florida, you can see the major city and state information per your request.

[image: Florida Area Codes]